# How can i log my Java Console output to Log1.txt, Log2.txt etc?

Tags: java, logging, text-files

How can i log my Java Console output to Log1.txt, Log2.txt etc?
Im currently using this code:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));

System.setOut(out);
```

But this replaces the old log which I do not want. I want it to for example if there is a log1.txt I want it to log to log2.txt not replace log1.txt
If anyone can help me out with this it would be GREAT!

Comment: What is a problem? You want to log output to 2 files together or you have problem with overwriting?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overwriting existing log files, you have to test to see whether the logfile already exists, or better yet, maintain a counter that tracks the number of log files that have already been created.

Somewhere, you have to have something like:

```
  int logCount = 1;

  PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output" + String.valueOf(logCount) + ".txt"));

  // Remember to increment the counter after the log file is written

  logCount++;
```

Comment: @michaldo OP's problem is overwriting files, not redirecting console to file. Please re-read carefully.

Comment: @MarcAtomic I'm confused, really. I'm sure I understand well, but I see next answer similar to you. OP must explain it better for me.

Comment: @michaldo OP clearly states: "But this *replaces the old log which I do not want.* I want it to for example if there is a log1.txt I want it to log to log2.txt not replace log1.txt" The problem is that he's overwriting files and wishes to name/rename them to avoid that issue. At no point does he indicate that the problem is "How to log to many files" in the sense of spreading output from one console to multiple files concurrently.

Comment: @MarcAtomic, take a look on snippet:       System.setOut(new PrintStream("o1.txt"));System.out.println("O1");System.setOut(new PrintStream("o2.txt"));System.out.println("O2"); I have no overwriting: o1.txt contains O1, o2.txt contains O2. Anyway, maybe you are right, but I suggest to suspend discussion until OP clarifies what he want.

Comment: @michaldo We can suspend discussion, but then we should suspend dishing out downvotes too. Seem fair to you?

Comment: @MarcAtomic Yes, but when I try undo my action I get "You last voted on this answer 1 hour ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." What now?

Comment: I have no issues writing to the console. I What what michaldo said which is: OP clearly states: "But this replaces the old log which I do not want. I want it to for example if there is a log1.txt I want it to log to log2.txt not replace log1.txt" The problem is that he's overwriting files and wishes to name/rename them to avoid that issue. At no point does he indicate that the problem is "How to log to many files" in the sense of spreading output from one console to multiple files concurrently.

Comment: @HitshotPlayZ Actually, I was the one who said that. Have you tried the modification I proposed in this answer? It's fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
try {
        String outputFileName = "output.txt";
        File file = new File(outputFileName);

        for(int i = 0; file.exists(); i++){
            file = new File("output"+i+".txt");              
        }

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

        System.setOut(out);          
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @HitshotPlayZ It must woks, I tested it. And all time when old files already exist created new file.